# backbone.js - getting extra data along with the request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection which holds some of the users. Some information that is needed is how many total there are, how many pages, etc. How do I pass these back to the client? Or do they have to come from a separate view in which case I will need more than one ajax call? I'd like to have the collection `fetch()` and also receive some of this "meta data". What's a good way for handling this?

Comment: Could you give more info? What does your server look like? What browsers do you need to support? How often do you get your data?

Comment: @tjameson My server is just nginx using php. I don't need to support any particular browsers (I can just support chrome & firefox if I want). I get my data relatively often (it's just crud operations) so changing the page number or doing a quick search etc.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Generally, you need to handle this in the collection class' parse method.  Its responsibility is to take the response and return back an array of model attributes.  However, you could do more than that if you wished if you didn't mind the parse method having this additional responsibility.

```
UserList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: User,

    url: '/users',

    parse: function(data) {
        if (!data) {
            this.registered_users = 0;
            return [];
        }
        this.registered_users = data.registered_users;
        var users = _(data.users).map(
            function(user_data) {
                var user = {};
                user['name'] = user_data.name;
                return user;
            }
        );
        return users;
    }
});
```

So in the trivial example above, presume the server returns a response which contains a count of registered users and and an array of user attributes.  You would both parse through and return the user attributes and you would pick off the registered user count and just set it as a variable on the model.
The parse method would get called as part of a fetch.  So no need to modify the fetch, just use the built-in hook method that you have.

Purists would say that you are giving the parse method a secondary responsibility which might surprise some people (e.g. returning something and modifying model state).  However, I think this is okay.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to override the `Collection::fetch()` method so that it parses this metadata out of the response. You could have your backend return a response like this:

```
{
    "collection": [
        { ... model 1 ... },
        { ... model 2 ... },
        ...
    ],
    "total_rows": 98765,
    "pages":      43
}
```

In your `fetch` method which overrides the original `Backbone.Collection::fetch()` method, you can handle each property of the object separately. Here's you could do the override with a slightly modified `fetch` method:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Collection.prototype, {
  fetch : function(options) {
    options || (options = {});
    var collection = this;
    var success = options.success;
    options.success = function(resp) {
      // Capture metadata
      if (resp.total_rows) collection.total_rows = resp.total_rows;
      if (resp.pages)      collection.pages      = resp.pages;

      // Capture actual model data
      collection[options.add ? 'add' : 'refresh'](
        collection.parse(resp.collection), options);

      // Call success callback if necessary
      if (success) success(collection, resp);
    };
    options.error = wrapError(options.error, collection, options);
    (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, 'read', this, options);
    return this;
});
```

Note that this approach using `_.extend` will affect **all** your classes which extend `Backbone.Collection`.

This way, you don't have to make 2 separate calls to the backend.

Comment: I don't think overriding a framework method is the right approach to solving this problem.  Instead, you want to live within the hook methods to accomplish what is being asked.  Parse seems like one appropriate place for this kind of thing.

Overriding a framework method leaves the danger that when you want to upgrade backbone.js, things may not work as expected or you may not be able to take advantage of any new functionality that had been assigned to that method.

Comment: You're right, generally you don't want to affect all methods inheriting from the framework prototype. For some reason I assumed the OP wanted this functionality on all Collection classes and overriding the framework method is a convenient way to do that. The  `parse` method does appear to be a better place to do this, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I would bootstrap the information at pagecreation. Write the information into the html document when the server creates the site. Like that you don't have to have an ajax call at all. I do that with the whole collection in ordner not to first load the page and then wait for the ajax call to return the information needed.

Code example with Python:

Line 64: https://github.com/ichbinadrian/maps/blob/master/python/main.py <- from here

Line 43: https://github.com/ichbinadrian/maps/blob/master/templates/index.html <- into here