# Why is meta-information not rendered in this MarionetteJS composite view?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am getting this unexpected behavior of loading meta information with a CompositeView with MarionetteJS. The JSON from server-side looks like:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "total": 2
    },
    "movies": [
        {
            "category": "Action",
            "description": "Another story goes ....",
            "id": 1,
            "stars": "4.0",
            "title": "My test movie"
        },
        {
            "category": "Action",
            "description": "the story goes....",
            "id": 2,
            "stars": null,
            "title": "my second movie"
        }
    ]
}
```

I use a Backbone collection to set the meta information like:

```
MA.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/api/movies.json',
  parse: function(data) {
    this.meta = new MA.Models.MetaMovie(data.meta);
    return data.movies;
  }
});

MA.addInitializer(function() {
  MA.Collections.Movies.model = MA.Models.Movie;
})
```

But when I try to access this meta variable from the CompositeView, the collection is initialized properly, while the meta information seems to be lost. Any ideas how to provide this meta information to the model of a CompositeView?

PS The console output looks like:

[image: composite view output]

Comment: You're only returning data.movies in your parse function.

Comment: correct. I was trying the approach that is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711245/backbone-js-getting-extra-data-along-with-the-request

Comment: If you post the code for the router/controller that creates your collection and view instances I will show you a clear way of accomplishing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! I am having the app here:  https://github.com/mulderp/moviedb/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/init.js -> then there is /views/composites with the meta view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a callback from fetch and use it to set the value of meta.total directly onto your metaMovie model instance

**movies.js:**

```
MA.addInitializer(function(){
  var self = this;
  var metaMovie = new MA.Models.MetaMovie({total: 1});

  MA.collections.movies = new MA.Collections.Movies();
  MA.composites.movies = new MA.Views.Composites.Movies({
    itemView: MA.Views.Items.Movie,
    model: metaMovie,
    collection: MA.collections.movies
  });
  var p = MA.collections.movies.fetch();

  // see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for details
  p.done(function(data) {
    self.metaMovie.set({total: data.total});
  });
});
```

Comment: Also, I need to trigger a render() with:  MA.composites.movies.render();  and then this works! Thanks!